# time series analysis: lag features

Tags: time-series, pandas, feature-engineering

I plan to include lag features in my multivariate time series data.

I have 17 input feature and one output feature. both input and output features are time series.
I will insert one more input feature by creating lag features of the output variable since it has high autocorrelation values for lag=1.

but I wonder if it is common practice to include lag features out of input features or do we only use this feature engineering technique for output feature?

Mehmet